# iPod touch 4 doesn't connect to WIFI

Tags: network, wifi, ipod-touch, ipod

The following bug is something that started occurring today...

Whenever I try to connect to any WIFI network (routers, mobile hotspots), I can see my iPod tries to connect, but instantly loses connection. When I try to do this manually, it connects but immediately shows a screen with address http://www.apple.com, the title of the screen is "Log In" and the screen contains:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>
```

The only thing I can do is press Cancel in the right top corner...
My ipod runs on iOS version 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Go to SETTINGS next to your networks name there's a blue arrow click on that.

2.) Now turn ON auto-join

3.) Turn OFF auto-log in

4.) It Works!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem this morning and it was solved by turning off the auto connection and auto log in.

Comment: Where can I find this setting? I have autoconnect off but can't find any autologin settings..

Answer (score -1):

Yeah auto-login was somehow turned on for me. Once I turned it off it worked.